# How to track progress event for Youtube Videos?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, dom-events

I want to trigger an event when Youtube video is complete by 25%,50%,75%,100%.

I didn't find any event for the progress of the videos.There are `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING,T.PlayerState.PAUSED,T.PlayerState.ENDED,T.PlayerState.BUFFERING`.

Is there any way through which I can trigger an event when video is completed by 25%,50% & so on...

I'm able to achieve the events like play, pause, stop. and currently I'm handling progress by call back function `setInterval()`. But problem is if page has multiple videos in that I'll not be able to get exact player object because it's global variable.

Here is Sample Code :-

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id='player'></div>

<script>
//set video values
var video = 'Xa0Q0J5tOP0'
video.h = '390'
video.w = '640'
var player;
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: video.h,
        width: video.w,
        videoId: video,
        events: {
            'onReady' :onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            //'onError': onPlayerError
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
setInterval(onPlayProgress, 1000);
};

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch (event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:

            if (cleanTime() == 0) {

                console.log("{'event': 'youtubeChange','eventCategory': 'video','eventAction': 'started','eventLabel':"+ video+"}");
            } else {

                console.log("{'event': 'youtubeChange','eventCategory': 'video','eventAction': 'played','eventLabel': 'v: ' "+ video + "' | t: '" + cleanTime()+"}");
                 console.log('currentTime:', player.getCurrentTime(), 'duration:', player.getDuration());
            };
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
            if (player.getDuration() - player.getCurrentTime() != 0) {
                console.log("{'event': 'youtubeChange','eventCategory': 'video','eventAction': 'paused','eventLabel': 'v: ' "+ video + "' | t: ' "+ cleanTime()+"}");
            };
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
             console.log("{'event': 'youtubeChange','eventCategory': 'video','eventAction': 'ended','eventLabel':"+ video+"}");
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
             console.log("{'event': 'youtubeChange','eventCategory': 'video','eventAction': 'Buffering','eventLabel':"+ video+"}");
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
             console.log("{'event': 'youtubeChange','eventCategory': 'video','eventAction': 'CUED','eventLabel':"+ video+"}");
            break;        
    };
};



function updateTimerDisplay(){
    // Update current time text display.
    $('#current-time').text(formatTime( player.getCurrentTime() ));
    $('#duration').text(formatTime( player.getDuration() ));
}

function formatTime(time){
    time = Math.round(time);

    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60),
    seconds = time - minutes * 60;

    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}


function cleanTime() {
    return Math.round(player.getCurrentTime())
};

function onPlayProgress() {
    viewedPercentage = player.getCurrentTime() / player.getDuration();
if (viewedPercentage >= 0.75) {
console.log("videoTime75");
} else if (viewedPercentage >= 0.5) {
console.log("videoTime50");
} else if (viewedPercentage >= 0.25) {
console.log("videoTime25");
}
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use ```setTimeout``` and ```duration``` of video to do that.

Comment: On the documentation I found this function: `player.getCurrentTime()`. Have you tried that?

Comment: but when i should trigger this event is still. because there is no OOTB event like Progress.

Comment: Of course, imagine an event triggering every miliseconds?

Comment: Use `setTimeour` like @TienDuong suggested with the even @MauriceNino talked about

Comment: Hi @vincent-d, I did that please check onPlayProgress method.